# Find which lists have same elements for large number of lists

Tags: python, list, set

I have a dictionary of lists (I could also make them sets)

```
mydict = {key1: [s11, s12, ...],
          key2: [s21, s22, ...],
          keyN: [sN1, sN2, ...]}
```

where s* are strings.  I'd like to identify which keys have equivalent lists.  I understand how to do pairwise comparison of two lists (==) or sets (intersection), but I need to collect all the keys that have matching lists.  For example:

```
common1 = [key1, key97]         # mydict[key1]==mydict[key97]
common2 = [key3, key42, key51]  # these keys from mydict have equivalent lists
```

Any efficient way to do this in Python?

Comment: Is this homework question. you have to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: No, not homework.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the order of the elements in the lists matters — correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = {} 
for k,v in mydict.items():
    result.setdefault(tuple(v), []).append(k)

commons = result.values()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# use sets as values so we don't have to worry about ordering
mydict = {
    '1': {'hi', 'bob'},
    '2': {'hi', 'sally'},
    '3': {'greetings', 'steve'},
    '4': {'sally', 'hi'},
    '5': {'salutations', 'mike'},
    '6': {'salutations', 'mike'},
}

common = []

# get a list of all the keys in mydict
keylist = list(mydict.keys())

# compare each key value to all the subsequent key values.
# if they match, add both keys to the common list
for position, key in enumerate(keylist):
    for key2 in keylist[position+1:]:
        if mydict[key] == mydict[key2]:
            common.append(key)
            common.append(key2)

print(common)
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution.  Check out Michael Ekoka's elegant solution.